# Execute binary inside symbolic link to separate LVM partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, lvm, symbolic-link, binary

I'm trying to execute a binary installer inside a folder, that is a symbolic link to another partition. The partition is a LVM logical volume, mapped through `/etc/fstab` like:

```
/dev/mapper/slow--vg-bulk--lv  /media/geovani/bulk  ext4  rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,users,async  0  0
```

Inside this partition, I created a folder called "Downloads", and sym-linked on home:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 geovani geovani    29 Mar 14 10:56 Downloads -> /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/
```

Inside the folder I have a binary file:

```
-rwxrwxr--  1 geovani geovani 27118787 Mar 17 13:06 genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin*
```

It seems that all permissions are correct, but when I try to execute it, I get:

```
$ ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
-bash: ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin: Permission denied
```

Anyone have an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: What are the mount options on the symlink *source* filesystem i.e. /media? if it's not mounted through fstab, you should be able to see by running the `mount` command with no arguments.

Comment: `/dev/mapper/slow--vg-bulk--lv on /media/geovani/bulk type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)`

It seems that my fstab's option "exec" has not been applied. How to fix this @steeldriver?

Comment: Got it. I removed the option "user" from /etc/fstab, and now "mount" reports:

`/dev/mapper/slow--vg-bulk--lv on /media/geovani/bulk type ext4 (rw)`

Now I can execute binaries inside this partition normally. Thank you @steeldriver!

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the option `user` (or `users`) from `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/slow--vg-bulk--lv  /media/geovani/bulk  ext4  rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,async  0  0
```

And now it executes normally.

Ref: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7462810.html#7462810

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a permissions issue, try this:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev/mapper/slow--vg-bulk--lv
sudo chmod a+rx ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
sudo chmod a+rx /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
```

Comment: Not worked :/, but thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer, try now.

Comment: `$ sudo chmod a+rx ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
    $ ls -l ./Downloads/
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 geovani geovani 27118787 Mar 17 13:06 genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
    $ ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
    -bash: ./Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin: Permission denied`

Comment: `$ sudo chmod a+rx /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
    $ ls -l /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 geovani geovani 27118787 Mar 17 13:06 genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin
    $ /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin 
    -bash: /media/geovani/bulk/Downloads/genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin: Permission denied`

Comment: Is a script or a ELF binary?

Comment: `$ find . -type f -exec file {} +`

`./genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin:  data`

Comment: Check my answer now.